# How to use collapsible on a promise base list?

Tags: javascript, list, drop-down-menu, promise

I am having this list which called from outside file **excel**, basically what it returns is something like this:

```
[
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0001",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",Roles: "Teacher 1"},
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0002",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",EmpNo: 107017,Fullname: "Krishna Patayan",Roles: "Teacher 1"}, 
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0003",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",EmpNo: 108224,Fullname: "Shiji Matthew",Roles: "Teacher 1"}, 
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0004",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",EmpNo: 108482,Fullname: "Aman George",Roles: "Teacher 2"}
]
```

This is how i displayed it on my html:

```
empList.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    data.map((x) => {
        if(x.Cat === 4000){ 
            //console.log(x)
            let container = document.querySelector('.container')
            
            let teacher = document.querySelector('.teacher')
            if(!teacher){
                teacher = document.createElement('div')
                teacher.className = 'teacher'
                teacher.id = 'card-stats'
                
                container.appendChild(teacher)
            }
            
            let job = document.createElement('button')
            job.className = 'cust-collapsible custom-collapsible-color'
            job.innerHTML = x.Code
            
            teacher.appendChild(job)
            if(x.EmpNo){
                let content = document.createElement('div')
                content.className = 'cust-content gradient-45deg-purple-green'
                
                let p = document.createElement('p')
                p.innerHTML = x.Fullname
                
                content.appendChild(p)
                teacher.appendChild(content)
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I also have this script to make my element collapsible whenever a user clicks this element:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('cust-collapsible');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
    });
}
```

My problem is once this has displayed on my HTML, my collapsible isn't working using the data that comes from my excel but if the list (static), say:

```
const empList = [
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0001",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",Roles: "Teacher 1"},
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0002",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",EmpNo: 107017,Fullname: "Krishna Patayan",Roles: "Teacher 1"}, 
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0003",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",EmpNo: 108224,Fullname: "Shiji Matthew",Roles: "Teacher 1"}, 
    {Cat: 4000,Code: "NSM0004",Department: "Natural Science and Mathematics",EmpNo: 108482,Fullname: "Aman George",Roles: "Teacher 2"}
]
```

is declared inside my **js** file, the collapsible works fine.

[image]

**What am I missing here? Any help is very much appreciated.**

Comment: Are you certain you are parsing the data properly once received from it's source?

Comment: Yes sir and based on the console log all data are parsed.